# django url parameters as form default value

Tags: django

I have a search form

```
class PostSearchForm(forms.Form):
    keyword = forms.CharField(label=_('Search'))
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(PostSearchForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        raise Exception(self.request)    # This returns none
        categories = Category.objects.filter(status=True)
        self.fields['categories'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=categories, widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'some-class'}))
```

Whenever search is made I have a build a form with default value as what they have searched, so what I tried is get the url parameters in form init and set the value but it was **returning None** due to some mistake. Can any one tell me where I am wrong

**Updated Question**

views.py

```
def get(self,request,category,*args,**kwargs):
    search_form = PostSearchForm()
    return render(request,self.template_name,{'search_form':search_form})
```

**Template**

```
<form method="get" action="." id="searchForm">
{{ search_form.keyword }}     # When searched then the value should be searched term
{{ search_form.categories }}
</form>
```

**URL**

```
http://example.com/?keyword=test
```

In the form I need to show **test** as value

Comment: Maybe you should show where you are using the form. Are you actually passing the request? (Although I can't see why you need it; you're not using it, and the way to do what you want is to pass in `initial` anyway.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman updated question please check

Comment: Well I can't understand how you're expecting this to work. You're clearly not passing request to the form, so how is it supposed to get into that method?

Comment: @DanielRoseman so how can I pass the request to the form

Comment: @DanielRoseman updated question with URL hope that should give much clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing can get into an object unless you pass it there. If you want the request in your object, then pass it:

```
search_form = PostSearchForm(request=request)
```

However this will not help you **in any way at all** and I'm confused about why you thought it would. If you want to pass in initial data for your form, do that:

```
search_form = PostSearchForm(initial={'categories': categories, 'keyword': keyword})
```